# Error of "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '0'", which doesn't occur on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js

My project is on https://immense-refuge-12167.herokuapp.com/

If I login (email: a@a.com, password: 11111111, or register then login), then click the "Browser" button at the top-left corner, an error will show up in the console as shown below:
`TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '0'`


**It only occurs on Heroku, not on localhost.**


The code where the error occurred is:

```
      async mounted() {
        if(this.$store.state.isUserLoggedIn){
          const bookmarksOfThisUser = (await api.getAllBookmarks(this.$store.state.user.id)).data;
          if(bookmarksOfThisUser.length != 0 && !!bookmarksOfThisUser){
            for(var bookmark in bookmarksOfThisUser){
              const song = (await api.getASong(bookmarksOfThisUser[bookmark]['songId'])).data;
              this.bookmarks.push(song)
            }
          }
        }
      },
```

I realized that it could be because `bookmarksOfThisUser` is of length 0, so I used `if(bookmarksOfThisUser.length != 0 && !!bookmarksOfThisUser)` to prevent it, but the error still occurred.

The `mounted` function is to populate the data `bookmarks`, which is an empty array by default. The element that uses this data is a `v-data-table` as shown below.

```
        <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="bookmarks"
          :items-per-page="5"
          class="elevation-1"
          v-if="this.bookmarks.length != 0"
        >
          <template v-slot:item.action="item">
            <v-btn class="primary" small v-bind:to="{name: 'viewSong', params:{
            songId: item.item.id
            }}">View</v-btn>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
```

I also checked its length with `v-if`, but the error still occurred...

Could anyone give me some hints about where I did wrong? And why it only occurs on Heroku not on localhost?

Thank you!

Comment: `bookmarksOfThisUser` is supposed to be an object NOT an array so `bookmarksOfThisUser.length != 0` is of no consequence. Instead do `if ( Object.keys(bookmarksOfThisUser).length )`

Comment: also you got html content on load `https://immense-refuge-12167.herokuapp.com/allBookmarks?userId=2`

Comment: @NikosM.Sry but the error still occurs. Please check out the heroku link in this post. Login then go to "Browser", the error will show up in console. I have modified my code as you indicated and pushed it to Heroku

Comment: Obviously, I was refering to a wrong condition, but your problem DOES NOT occur because `bookmarksOfThisUser` is of zero length, it is another cause. I was simply correcting your condition test but this is not the cause of the problem

Comment: your variable is most likely a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code could check that it received the expected data response and then handle that error condition.

For example, you could check for the data type:

```
const response = await api.getAllBookmarks(this.$store.state.user.id);
const bookmarksOfThisUser = response.data;

if (Array.isArray(bookmarksOfThisUser)) {
    for(var bookmark in bookmarksOfThisUser){
        const song = (await api.getASong(bookmarksOfThisUser[bookmark]['songId'])).data;
        this.bookmarks.push(song)
    }
} else {
    // example only of logging the data that is not as expected
    console.log({response})
    console.log({bookmarksOfThisUser})
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Using you code I found thar it is because my database doesn't work, so the data returned is never an array.

Comment: Happy to hear it helped you find the core issue!